# programming of 3 x 7

Tags: c, buffer-overrun

I have been trying to program the 3x 7 trick. The full code is available here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/9419/programming-of-3-x-7-trick.

I am stuck at step 5.

[image]

I have this error when i type in the value for the row.

[image]

Not sure what the error is. Need some guidance.

step 6: [image]

Comment: Debugger is your runtime friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error comes from the back_to_array function, where you have a typo in the condition of the inner loop. It should be `j < numRows` instead of `i < numRows`.

Comment: Also, as Mahesh suggests, you should get familiar with the debugger, as more problems are likely to happen and it's the right way to find and fix them.

Comment: Ah, you were one minute faster. :) However, there are other problems with the program as well, but this bug should be fixed first.

Comment: @AndersSjöqvist can you point out other mistakes to me as well? will be very grateful to you...

Comment: @lakesh I had a case where two numbers kept popping up on the same row during all attempts, and the program picked the one I wasn't thinking of. Trying to track down that bug now.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is the mistake with `i < numRows` instead of `j < numRows`.

As per requested, here are some other modifications you could and should implement:

- Write `printf("%8i", ...` instead of `printf("%i\t", ...`, since the latter is likely to spread out the numbers unevenly.
- Sanitize your input. Right now, you can make the program crash by inputting strange values. (Also, give the user a hint about whether to use the values 0, 1, 2 or 1, 2, 3.)
- Right now, you're not shuffling row 0 and column 0. For instance, you start with column 6 and go through the columns one by one, but you stop as soon as you reach 0, before entering the loop again.
- There's a problem where you quite often notice that the same numbers occur together on the same row. I believe, although I'm not completely sure, that the problem is that you're sorting the rows. The point of placing the selected row in the middle of the deck all the time, is to make the selected card move towards the center. If you sort the row, you allow the card to move away from the center. I commented out the sorting and couldn't notice the problem anymore. Is there a reason why you sort the rows?
- Regarding design: Personally, I'd not display a shuffled array and wait for a keystroke before beginning. Instead, I'd write the instructions and immediately ask the player to enter a number. I always tried to enter a number already after the first array had been displayed. Very annoying. :)

Comment: thanks for pointing out.. Regarding the fourth point you made, i uploaded the instructions given to me in the question... maybe i misread the question

Comment: regarding the fifth point, the instructions was to lay the card face up before the game starts

Comment: @lakesh Ok, I see your point, but when they wrote "sort the numbers in bundles" I believe they meant "create a pile from each row". Still, you should try both solutions a number of times to see if you agree with me. I might be wrong. Regarding the final one, I think you could have displayed the cards without shuffling them. It actually doesn't say that they need to be shuffled before they're displayed the first time. But it's up to you of course. Good luck! ;)

Comment: how do you make the output stay on the screen? everytime i run the answer function, it quits before even i can see the answer.

Comment: @lakesh That's a tough one. The easiest solution would be to run the program from the command line. The output will remain after termination. A quick-and-dirty solution is `while('\n'!=getchar()) {} while('\n'!=getchar()) {}`. The first one should catch the newline after the last number, and the second should make the program wait for input. There might be some Windows thing you could try that I don't know about, but on a Unix-based system I'd suggest linking with [ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses). Also, you should probably finish with a newline or `fflush(stdout)`.